# how can get value with out refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

all city  displayed   in to side bar,when i click on the one city i want company list of that city an all  city in to side bar,
and ya all cities are come from table based on state_id means dynamically,

for getting all city i written.this code

```
<?php
 $s_name= $_POST["submit"];

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
    mysql_select_db("itcompanylist");

    $query  = "SELECT s_id FROM states WHERE `state_name` = '$s_name'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
//echo $row['s_id'];


 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT city_name FROM `city` WHERE s_id ='".$row['s_id']."'");

$i = 0;

echo "<form method='post' action='demo2.php'><table border='1' ><tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
 echo '<td><input type="submit" name="ok" value="'.$row['0'].'"></td>'; 


  if ($i++ == 2) 
  { 
     echo "</tr><tr>";
     $i=0;
  }
}

echo "</tr></table></form>";

?>
```

-thank you

Comment: That sounds like a job for Javascript. PHP is located on the Server, so to access it you need to make a server request, which, in PHP, means refreshing. You can use AJAX.

Comment: First you have to fix your SQL injection security hole (simply calling `$s_name` is bad as the user might send what he wishes). Then you have to move to MySQLi or PDO because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: [scolding] For 536829921807th time, don't use `mysql_` functions. Use PDO instead. [/scolding] Use ajax for client-server interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ajax for this purpose.

To learn more about ajax please read.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

Answer (score 0):

In your html page, make an `onclick` event on your cities to a function. XXX is the id you want to pass:

```
<div onclick="onCity('XXX')">City A</div>
```

Inside the function, use jquery to get the state info by passing a state ID.
And for example, use the output to display on a div which its `id="myDiv"`:

```
<script>
function onCity(id){
    $.post('getstate.php', {state_id:id}, function(output) {
        $('#myDiv').html(output);
    });
}
</script>
```

in your php, simply use `$_POST` to get the ID:

```
<?php
$stateID=$_POST['state_id'];
//using the state ID ...
//echo some values as the output
?>
```